# Memory in an Artificial Neural Network

Tags: neural-network

I am just starting to get into the world of Neural networks, using my own objects, and vectors, in the language of C++.

However, I was thinking that a neural network in a game like Super Mario would have a difficult time based on just the screen for input, and the keyboard (or controller) for output, since the net has no way of finding out the velocity of the player, or any of it's past moves.

I thought that if a neural network had "memory", like where some of the output of the previous feed-forward were fed back into the net, along with the normal inputs, this could work to give the neural net a slight sense of what it could have been doing, and thus affect it's current output.

Is There a better way of giving a neural net "memory" by feeding part of it's output into it's input?

I would appreciate any helpful links, Thanks in advance.

PS: My choice of language is c++.

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question properly, but you should take a look at Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) which do just that, "they are networks with loops, allowing information to persist" [RNN](https://medium.com/explore-artificial-intelligence/an-introduction-to-recurrent-neural-networks-72c97bf0912)

Comment: As for neural networks in games, developers usually build their own environments to try out the AI.

Comment: Thank you to Ach113, RNN is just what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to be of help, I will move my comment as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recurrent Neural Networks (RNN) do just what you described. You can read more about them here: [RNNs](https://medium.com/explore-artificial-intelligence/an-introduction-to-recurrent-neural-networks-72c97bf0912)